# Laravel 4 Eloquent Two Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My tables

**Modelos**
id
nome slug
marca_id

**Pecas**
id
codigo

**modelo_peca**
modelo_id
peca_id

**produtos**
id
categoria_id
codigo
nome

**categorias**
id
nome
slug

I have these models

```
class Modelo extends Eloquent
{

   public function pecas()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Peca');
   }

}
```

---

```
class Peca extends Eloquent {

    public function modelos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Modelo');
    }

    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Produto');
    }

}
```

---

```
class Produto extends Eloquent {

    public function pecas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Peca');
    }

}
```

---

I´m trying to create a route that pass all the products related to a modelo to a view. What´s wrong?

```
Route::get('/modelo/{slug?}', function($slug = null) {
if ($slug) {
    $id = Modelo::where('slug', $slug)->pluck('id');
    $pecas = Modelo::find($id)->pecas;
    $produtos = Peca::where('id', $pecas)->get();
}
return View::make('produto.home')->with('produtos', $produtos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use eager loading

Off the top of my head (also across the language barrier I'll do my best)
You seem to want all Products (`produtos`) for a specific page category other taxonomy (may be wrong but you can adjust the code as needed)

The `where()` method expects three parameters iirc so instead the first query would be `$id = Modelo::where('slug', '=', $slug)->pluck('id');`
The same would apply to the other where statements.

Full query:

```
if($slug) 
{
    $query = Modelo::with('pecas.produto')
        ->where('slug', '=', $slug)
        ->get();

    $produtos = $query->produto;
}

return View::make('produto.home')->with('produtos', $produtos);
```

Here I've taken a different approach and eager loaded the relations, I'm not 100 percent sure this is how you want this to be done but it hopefully gives you a foundation for using your relations properly in Eloquent.

You don't need to manually get primary keys and perform multiple queries, check out the Eloquent documentation on the Laravel website.